# Strange java.sql.SQLException: Column 'fk_Content' not found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have two tables in MySQL Database:

**1- campaign:**

- **pkid**: primary key.
- **fk_Content**: foreign key on content table.
- **tk_DistributionGroup**: foreign key on type table distribution_group.

**2- content:**

- **pkid**: primary key.
- **tk_contentSubtype**: foreign key on type table distribution_list.

I have java bean (not hibernate entity) called CampaignData

```
public class CampaignData {

    private long contentId;
    private long contentSubTypeId;
    private Long distributionGroupId;

}
```

here's how i am doing the query:

```
CampaignData campaignData = (CampaignData) session
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "select camp.fk_Content as contentId,camp.tk_DistributionGroup as distributionGroupId,cont.tk_contentSubtype as contentSubTypeId "
                                + "from campaign camp,content cont"
                                + " where camp.pkid=:campaignId and camp.fk_Content=cont.pkid")
                .setLong("campaignId", campaignId)
                .setResultTransformer(
                        Transformers.aliasToBean(CampaignData.class))
                .uniqueResult();
```

which produces the hibernate query:

```
select
        camp.fk_Content as contentId,
        camp.tk_DistributionGroup as distributionGroupId,
        cont.tk_contentSubtype as contentSubTypeId 
    from
        campaign camp,
        content cont 
    where
        camp.pkid=? 
        and camp.fk_Content=cont.pkid
```

when i try the produced SQL query in the database, it works fine and data is retrieved successfully, but when running the application i get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2297)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:859)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.Main.getCampaignSMSs(Main.java:43)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'fk_Content' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBigDecimal(ResultSetImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.type.BigIntegerType.get(BigIntegerType.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(CustomLoader.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    ... 9 more
```

please advise why i am getting the exception.

**UPDATE:** this is a 3rd party application that connects on the database for another application.

the other application value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

Comment: I might be  wrong.. but can you rename the fk_Content to something else and and see if it works? It is just that fk_ is conventionally discovered as an foreign key constraint and I dont know if Hibernate is treating it specially..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get it to work i needed to use addScalar as follows:

```
.createSQLQuery(
                        "select camp.fk_Content as contentId,camp.tk_DistributionGroup as distributionGroupId,cont.tk_contentSubtype as contentSubTypeId "
                                + "from campaign camp,content cont"
                                + " where camp.pkid=:campaignId and camp.fk_Content=cont.pkid")
                .addScalar("contentId")
                .addScalar("distributionGroupId")
                .addScalar("contentSubTypeId")
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to properly get from the database what you request, the Entity classes that hibernate uses should match 100% the database tables.

You have the column `fk_Content` but the private field is `contentId`. Just using the `as` won't get you the desired result. If you want to use different names (like you did), you need to provide hibernate with the proper column names, using `@Column(name = "")`. Furthermore, using basic data types is not recommended. Your CampaignData class would look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class CampaignData {

    private Long contentId;
    private Long contentSubTypeId;
    private Long distributionGroupId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pkid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getContentId() {
        return this.contentId;
    }

    public void setContentId(Long contentId){
        this.contentId = contentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "fk_Content")
    public Long getContentSubTypeId() {
        return this.contentSubTypeId;
    }

    public void setContentSubTypeId(Long contentSubTypeId){
        this.contentSubTypeId= contentSubTypeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "tk_DistributionGroup")
    public Long getDistributionGroupId() {
        return this.distributionGroupId;
    }

    public void setDistributionGroupId(Long distributionGroupId){
        this.distributionGroupId= distributionGroupId;
    }
}
```

This should do it. Also, try learning to use [Hibernate's Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html). It's a far more better practice than hard-coded SQL statements.

Comment: my above code is a sql query and i set the values in aliases and transform the aliases into a bean.